# How to read a csv file from S3 using dask and mentioning my access key and secret?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-science, dask

I am trying to read a CSV file from S3 using dask but I am getting the following error. Can anyone please correct me If I'm doing anything wrong here?

```
aws_access_key_id = 'xxxx'
aws_secret_access_key = 'xxxx'
df = dd.read_csv('s3://{bucket}/{file_key.csv}', storage_options = {'key': aws_access_key_id, 'secret': aws_secret_access_key})
```

Error I am facing:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

Comment: Please give your complete traceback. It seems like it might be as simple as a misplaced comma - so the closer the code you post is to what you actually run, the better!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto3 to create S3 connection with access key ID and secret access key.

```
    import boto3
     import io
    import dask as dd
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket,s3_key)
    file = response["Body"].read()
    df = dd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file))
```

Note:Export keys in environment using os.env.

Comment: Please don't do this! You are downloading the whole file into memory, but Dask is designed to be able to read partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I used boto3 and this is similar to read a csv from S3 using pandas. This worked out for me!

```py
import boto3
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('s3://*****.csv', storage_options = {'key': 'XXXX', 'secret': 'XXXX'}, assume_missing=True)
```